# Searching in a row wise sorted 2D n x n Matrix

Tags: algorithm, sorting, search

How to search an element in a row wise sorted 2D n x n Matrix.
Can be done in `O(nlogn)` by using binary search for each row and `O(nlog(logn))` by using interpolation search for each row.
Any `O(n)` solution?

Constraint : The array contains integers.

Example : Searching 32 in the given 5x5 matrix.

```
0 5 6 8 42 98

-4 -1 3 21 455

-4 0 3 4 4

0 0 0 0 0

0 [32] 64 244 333
```

Kindly help.

Comment: The rows are sorted, but the columns are not. So O(n) isn't possible.

Comment: So, the best being O(nlog(logn))?

Comment: Your example doesn't hold any extra value. Also, the second row is not sorted.

Comment: It's not necessary that always there will be an extra value,there can be >=0 instances of the element to be found. Second row fixed.

Comment: `O(n)` is certainly possible.  Scanning every element in an array is a canonical example of an `O(n)` operation.  Assertions to the contrary are based on the misunderstanding that `n` represents the size of one dimension of the array; for complexity analysis it most certainly does not, it represents the number of elements in the array. If you doubt this, and think that scanning every element in an array is `O(n^2)` then just reshape the array to a vector (`O(1)` because it is just twiddling with indices) and scan the vector ... magically turning an `O(n^2)` operation into an `O(n)` one. Pshaw.

Comment: @RajarshiSarkar What I mean is that your example doesn't really clarify anything in the question.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I disagree. By definition, an algorithm running in *O(n)* time means that execution time is proportional to the *n* defined in the algorithm. If the matrix size is defined as *n×n*, this means that scanning through each element once takes *O(n²)* no matter what.

Comment: @EitanT: you're welcome to disagree.  Take the example of scanning a vector, `O(n)` where `n` is the number of elements in the vector.  Now, replace `n` by `m==sqrt(n)`.  That does not transform the algorithm from `O(n)` to `O(m^2)`, scanning a vector is linear in the number of elements in the vector not quadratic. Mis-measuring the size of the input doesn't change the complexity of an algorithm, if that were possible I could write an `O(n)` algorithm for matrix-matrix multiplication by judicious choice of `n`.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark If the length of the vector is *n*, there is no point in defining *m = sqrt(n)*, but the algorithm would in fact run at *O(n)* or *O(m²)*. Were your input to have *n* rows and *k* columns, scanning each element once would take *O(nk)* by definition. There is no meaning in the Big O notation without the respective definition of *n*, you cannot assume what it is. In this question *n* is clearly defined, thus scanning each element would take *O(n²)*.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark The questions says `"n x n Matrix"`, any other assumption about what `n` means will be incorrect. And I'm inclined to say that, for any problem with multiple reasonable definitions of "input size", which one `n` refers to should be explicitly specified.

Answer (score 0):

Search for **x** in matrix **M**[m*n] (m rows,n columns).
I think that the best option is incorrect row skipping.
 - if x is out of range of row(r) then skip searching in it
And on top of that simply apply binary (or index bit approximation) search

```
const int n=...;
const int m=...;
double x=...,A[m][n]={...};
int r,i,j,j0; 
double *p;
// init bit mask for index approximation
for (j=1;j<n;j<<=1); j>>=1; if (!j) j=1; j0=j;
// search
for (r=0;r<m;r++)   // all rows
 if (x>=A[r][0])    // skip if x is too low
  if (x<=A[r][n-1]) // skip if x is too high
   {
   // index approximation search in row r
   for (p=A[r],i=0,j=j0;j;j>>=1)
    {
    i|=j;
    if ((i>=n)||(x<p[i])) i^=j;
    if (x==p[i]) return "x found in A[r][i]";
    }
   }
return "x not found";
```

On complexity your N is m*n and the algorithm is:

```
Omin(m+  log2(n))
Omax(m+m*log2(n))
```

if (m==n) then we can rewrite it in N=n*n order more simply:

```
Omin(sqrt(N)+   log2(sqrt(N)) )
Omax(sqrt(N)*(1+log2(sqrt(N))))
```

if not then n->N/m and m->N/n so:

```
Omin((N/n)+   log2(sqrt(N/m)) )
Omax((N/n)*(1+log2(sqrt(N/m))))
```

As you can see complexity depends strongly on matrix values and goes from Omin to Omax. Program should be changed to meet your interface and enviroment and also return values are just to show what happend and should be changed to meet your needs.

Answer (score -1):

Though a quite an Old Post but still.

Start from top right corner or bottom left corner (any side you can pick).Suppose we pick top right.
      Compare the key with the matrix element.

```
 if(key==matrix[i][j])
      return true;
   if(key<matrix[i][j])
         then move towards left(j--)
   else      //if the key is greater than the matrix element
         then move towards down (i++);
```

worst case time complexity is  when we need to travel one complete row and one complete column so O(n+n) =O(n).